# Swipe is not working in ios devices

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I have a app that want to allow contacts from a device event. I used
    (`autoAlertAccept`,true) but that won't work for me. I am using **appium 1.5.2** and
    even I want to swipe that particular contact to chat or call with
    that particular contact.  When I used a:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ImageButton")).click();
    size1 = driver.manage().window().getSize();   
    System.out.println(size1);    int x1 = (int) (size1.width * 0.70);

       int x2 = (int) (size1.width * 0.30);

       int starty =size1.height / 2;

       System.out.println(x1 + x2 + starty);

      driver.findElement(By.name("Demo Usr"));   
    driver.swipe(x1,starty,x2,starty,3000);
```

I found some exception

Comment: have a found a solution yet?

Comment: not yet ...still facing this error

Comment: to remove my confusion, u actually move an element to another element or u want to swipe the screen form left to right?

Comment: i have a list of contacts and all the contacts have swipe to perform some action for example i have jyotsana in my contact list and i want to swipe that contact from right to left to perform action (there are three option call, chat, vedio call)

Answer (score 0):

ur provided code will swipe the screen from left to right. But to move an element from one position to another, use the below code:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("ur xpath"));//get element locator as ur wish by accesibility id or xpath. 

int startX = elem.getLocation().getX();
int startY = elem.getLocation().getY();

//this will swipe from right to left horizontally
driver.swipe(startX,startY,startX-90,startY,2000);
// use 90 or more according to ur screen position

//this will swipe from left to right horizontally
driver.swipe(startX,startY,startX+90,startY,2000);

//u must have to be sure that this location is within the screen, otherwise u will get an error
```

If there is any issue let me know.

Comment: in 1.5.2 don't use By.name.... use By.accessibilityId .... in 1.5.2 By.name is deprecated.

Comment: Which driver u used ios driver or anything else?

Comment: i import java client then getting error that change driver to mobile driver

Comment: no need to import anything.... u can do it by using ur driver if u use appium ios driver like new IOSDriver<WebElement>

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
 at Boku.BokuWithLogin.main(BokuWithLogin.java:42)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113331/discussion-between-noor-and-jyotsana-namdev).

Comment: i updated my answer, now u can check the updated answer and let me know

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: point is not within the bounds of the screen (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: ok thats because of position problem what i told u in my answer. so use value less than 90 for ex. 20 or 30

Comment: I did for 10 to 80 nothing happend